# Convert diamond matrix 2d coordinates to 1d index and back

Tags: matrix, spiral

I have a 2d game board that expands as tiles are added to the board. Tiles can only be adjacent to existing tiles in the up, down, left and right positions.

So I thought a diamond spiral matrix would be the most efficient way to store the board, but I cannot find a way to convert the x,y coordinates to a 1d array index or the reverse operation.

like this layout

```
  X -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
Y 3          13
  2       24  5 14
  1    23 12  1  6  15  
  0 22 11  4  0  2   7 16
 -1    21 10  3  8  17
 -2       20  9 18
 -3          19
```

Tile 1 will always be at position 0, tile 2 will be at 1,2,3 or 4, tile 3 somewhere from 1 to 12 etc.

So I need an algorithm that goes from X,Y to an index and from an index back to the original X and Y.

Anyone know how to do this, or recommend another space filling algorithm that suits my needs.  I'm probably going to use Java but would prefer something language neutral.

Thanks

Comment: I think this link might have a solution; http://www.mangband.org/developer/browser/trunk/src/server/wilderness-hold.c?rev=131

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand form the problem statement, there is no guarantee that the tiles will be filled evenly on the sides. for example:

```
  X -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
Y 3                 6
  2           3  4  5
  1           1      
  0           0  2  
 -1
```

So, I think a diamond matrix won't be the best choice.
I would suggest storing them in a hash-map, like implementing a dictionary for 2 letter words. 
[image: Example for a hash-map dictionary.[1]]
Also, You need to be more specific to what your requirements are. Like, do you prioritize space complexity over time? Or do you want a fast access time and don't care about memory usage that much.

**IMPORTANT :**

Also, what is the

- Max number of tiles that we have to hold
- Max width and height of the board.

Comment: Both the max number of tiles and max width and height are unknown. (there may be a practical limit of about 100 tiles so therefore the max dimensions would be 200x200) The game board could grow any direction.  Which is why I didn't think a 2d array would be suitable, I'd have to arbitrarily put a limit on the board size.  I guess a HashMap with a 2d coordinate as the key would be the most suited. There isn't speed or size issue to warrant a novel solution. I just wanted to see if something existed to represent it. Thanks.

Comment: If that's the case, and you don't really care about  space and time, then the hash-map really might be the best option for generic operations. If there's a specific operation that you need to do over and over again, then we could think of optimizing it to that operation.